# Error al compilar, pero en la lista de errores no me sale nada

Tags: c#, visual

Buen dia

estoy intentando debuggear mi solucion pero me sale un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no me sale ninguno en la consola de errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido. Tal vez no estés veas los errores en la lista pero en la ventana **Output** están listados los errores de compilación. En la primera imagen se puede ver.